# default affectation in PHP

Tags: php, operator-keyword, ternary

**EDIT : My bad, I made a mistake, when I said null in this post I meant to say null or empty or zero or false or whatever that makes (!$x) true.**

with a friend, we are trying to find the best way to affect a value to a variable if this variable is null.
We want to do this:

```
if (!$x)
    $x = 5;
```

My friend suggested a one line solution:

```
!$x && $x = 5;
```

Here, if $x is null, then $x = 5 will be interpreted by PHP so $x will contain 5.
If $x is not null the second part of the line won't be read and $x will keep its old value.

Resume:
$x null: one get, one comparison, one set.
$x not null: one get, one comparison

I tryied to do cleaner AND better. First, I came to this:

```
$x = $x ? $x : 5;
```

but here if $x were previously not null, then PHP will do an extra affectation ($x = $x), plus, this line is longer than the previous one.
Resume:
$x null: one get, one comparison, one set.
$x not null: two get, one comparison, one set ($x = $x).

Then I came to this:

```
$x = $x ?: 5;
```

We have less operations than the previous one and we have one character less than the first one.
Resume:
$x null: one get, one comparison, one set.
$x not null: one get, one comparison, one set ($x = $x).

But my question is, when PHP have to do this:

```
$x = $x;
```

Is it really doing it? If not, the third solution (the last one) is the best. Otherwise, the first solution is the best one.

Is there other solutions to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: keep in mind: `null` is not the same as `false`

Comment: That very very much depends on the context. Ideally you'll be writing short self-contained functions to begin with, so `$x` could be a function argument with a default value. Then this question would be pointless. Beyond that, do whatever you want; but be aware that less code is not necessarily a desirable goal. The result must be readable and readily understandable, not as-obfuscated-as-possible.

Comment: Assuming that you're looking for "best" as in "fastest", there's no substitute for trying it out yourself!

Answer (score 0):

"the best" solution is always to compare types

```
if ($x)
```

This if is equivalent of

```
if ($x == true)
```

but it is not the same as

```
if ($x === true)
```

This:

```
if (!$x)
```

is the same as

```
if ($x != true)
```

Showing you the problem behind this tries to short it:

```
$x = false;

if (!$x)
    $x = 5;
```

`false` and `null` evaluate both to true in `(!$x)`.

When you want to be sure, you don't shorten it. The **best** is strict comparison:

```
$x = ($x !== null) ? $x : 5;
```

As deceze already said, shortening the code might lead to confusion. `$x` can have different values which result in unexpected behaviour when you don't stricly compare it to the desired content. Examples:

```
$x = '';
$x = null;
$x = false;
$x = 0;
$x = 1;
$x = new stdClass;
```

What happens, when you put all these into an if without strict comparison (`if ($x)`) ?

Make plenty use of:

```
if ($x === null)
if ($x !== false)
if ($x !== 0)
if ($x instanceof stdclass)
```